# Pass value into new window with ClientSide JS in XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages

I would like to pass values of 4 fields in to new XPages with ClientSide JavaScript

Find below what i tried so far, I cannot put values into field in the new XPages :(

//Client Side JS pass values to the new window

```
var cFld = document.getElementById("#{id:fieldNameID}").innerHTML ;
myUrl = "http://serveradres/applicationame.nsf/xspFrmTest.xsp?action=newDocument";
var zWindow = window.open(myUrl, '_blank');
var zDoc = zWindow.document;
zDoc.getElementById("#{id:fieldNameID2}").value = "TEST VALUE";
```

**UPDATE 1:**
the new page i would like to open is in the another application. So i cannot carry any values with any type of scopes (Application, session, etc...)
thinking about sample below. From  xspfrmtest.xsp to xspfrmtest2.xsp

1. Application1.nsf -> xspfrmtest.xsp
2. Application2.nsf -> xspfrmtest2.xsp

Comment: Why not add these field values to the SessionScope and read the these values from the SessionScope in the new XPages

Comment: Why is there a space after zWindow - "var zDoc = zWindow .document;
zDoc.document.getElementById("#{id:fieldNameID2}").value = "TEST VALUE";" AND why are you calling .document twice?

Comment: Keep in mind that referencing with "#{id:fieldname}" only works for components/fields on the **current** XPage. I would use the approach of @FrankvanderLinden (see comment above), but if you want to exclusively use client-side JavaScript you would have to write something like this: `zWindow.document.querySelector('[id$=":fieldname"]').value="TEST VALUE";`

Comment: @pipalia This is just a copy paste mistake. In my page the code is correct.

Comment: PS: You could also provide the field values as url parameters (for example `...&field1=value1`) and set the computed value of the target component to `#{param.field1}`.

Comment: some field values is too long :( I thought that sometime URL Parameter may not handle that's why I did not try :( 
Thank you..

Comment: As Frank suggested, this is pretty much what sessionScope is for.  If you put values in there then any page the user goes to can access them.

Comment: @David No, all scope variables including sessionScope work only **within** one .nsf and not across different .nsf databases.

Comment: ah ok.  Thanks @Knut I missed that part.  Funny I just had to do this recently and because I use the OpenNTF Domino API - that project provides a "serverScope" which allows scoped variables to work with multiple .nsf's.  Has to be the same server though of course.

Comment: I have installed that API but I could not understand OpenNTF Domino API. I mean how to use it :( if you don't mind is it possible to redirect me to some pages where i can find samples or sample codes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for transferring (large) field values between XPages of different Domino databases on **client side**:

Database One.nsf with XPage One.xsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputText
        id="fieldOne"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:button
        value="Open Two.xsp in Two.nsf"
        id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                window.open("http://server1/Two.nsf/Two.xsp", '_blank');
            ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Database Two.nsf with XPage Two.xsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            var fieldOne = window.opener.document.querySelector('[id$=":fieldOne"]');
            if (fieldOne) {
                window.document.getElementById("#{id:fieldTwo}").value = fieldOne.value;
            }
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:inputText 
        id="fieldTwo"></xp:inputText>   
</xp:view>
```

The second XPage uses `window.opener` onClientLoad to get a handle to first XPage's window and reads field values from there then.

Comment: result turns as "Undefined" :( while transferin that data value disappears. I don't know why?

Comment: It works for Domino 9.0.1 FP5 with IE 11, Chrome 50 or Firefox 46 at least. I created both databases from scratch without additional settings. You have to adapt the URL (server:port) though.